# batch file to arrange database files that create a new folder every 1st of the month and store data in it

Tags: database, file, batch-file, scripting

I have a pc that is recording files and storing them in a folder called archive, that folder is getting too big and the files becoming messy in there. i want to create a batch script that **move files that are older then 4 months** store them in "D:\new" backup folder and **create a new folder in D:\new every 1st of a month** and **move new files from the recording folder to the new created folder** which has a name as MM-DD-YYYY as per creating date.

thanks you so much!

Comment: Fine. And what is your question? This is not a site for requesting code for free, it is a site for programmers asking specific questions. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: The obvious solution to stop recording aside, use the task scheduler for the new folder every month and `forfiles` for moving the files older than 4 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you I will create a schedule that run every 1st of the month and use:
**set drive=D:\new\%D%** as D is defined as the current date.

I will use also : **IF NOT EXIST “%drive%” mkdir “%drive%”** 
so if folder exist do not create a new folder, if we are in a new month the date will not be matching with the one that exist so it will create a new folder.

I will use: **robocopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%drive%" %FileMask%**
to move files to that new folder sorted by it name by date!